# How to change font color of selection toolbar when i select text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter app where I'm using a TextField. When I select text in the TextField, a selection toolbar appears with options like cut, copy, and paste. However, the text color of these options is not visible because the toolbar color is white and the text color is also white. This makes it difficult for users to see the options.

In my app, I'm using both light and dark themes. In the light theme, the toolbar and text color are both white, and in the dark theme, they are both black.

Is there a way to change the text color of the options in the selection toolbar independently of the toolbar color? I'd like to ensure good visibility of the options regardless of the theme.

I've tried setting the cursorColor property in the textSelectionTheme, but it only affects the cursor color, not the text color of the toolbar options.

[image: Screenshot of App]

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your widget with a Theme and specify the textSelectionColor within its ThemeData:

```
Container(
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      textSelectionColor: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    child: SelectableText(
      'this is a text',
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I want to select font in TextFormField widget.